# Simulated key press

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to make a very simple program, and I need to simulate a key press. I have tried to find a solution, but my program doesn't seem to know any of the methods that is suggested. I don't know if that is because I'm using a console aplication or what the deal is, but isn't there a simple what to send a virtual key press, that the computer will react to as if the user itself hit the button?

Comment: Your question is very poor in quality.  Some more information regarding *exactly* what you are trying to accomplish is needed.

Comment: "Simulating Key Press c#" downt wotk for me. In the answer by Thejaka Maldeniya, I found out that i needed to use System.Windows.Forms. But now i get that error I responded with. 
I simply need to simulate a key press. Say i wanted to simulate the space button for instance. If I'm in Word, it will make a space, if I'm in VLC, it will pause the video, if I'm in a game, I might jump.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you want to simulate key presses for your own application or a third-party application/window that happens to be running on the computer. I'll assume the latter.

The following minimal example will send `Hello world!` to one instance of *notepad*, which you have to start manually.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get the 'notepad' process.
    var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if (notepad == null)
        throw new Exception("Notepad is not running.");

    // Find its window.
    IntPtr window = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero,
        "Edit", null);

    // Send some string.
    SendMessage(window, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "Hello world!");
}
```

([full code](https://gist.github.com/Virtlink/8429401))

It uses these PInvoke methods and constants:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent,
    IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg,
    int wParam, string lParam);

private const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
```

Google is your friend when you want to learn more about how to get a handle on the application you want, PInvoke, and sending messages to other applications.